# Opencart Devo ignorar no GIT o arquivo checked.cache?

Tags: git, ssh

estou tendo um pouco de estresse com o arquivo checked.cache do opencart que a cada atualização pede para fazer um add/commit/push e toda vez que isso tem que ser feito eu tenho dores de cabeça com conflitos e etc. eu devo adicionar este arquivo à meu `.gitignore` ?

Answer (score 1):

Adicione no seu arquivo `.gitignore`:

```
*/checked.cache   # elimina somente arquivos com este nome
*.cache           # elimina todos os arquivos .cache
```

Se você já tiver comitado algum arquivo que não deseje, não vai adiantar somente adicionar no `.gitignore`. Você terá de remover o arquivo, comitar a exclusão do mesmo, e além disso adicionar o nome do arquivo no .gitignore.